# How to convert list into string with quotes Dart

Tags: dart

I have a list and want it as a string with quotes `List myList = [1,2,3]`

require O/P as `List myList = ["1","2","3"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this works as you need!

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  List myList = [1, 2, 3];
  List myNewList = [];

  myList.forEach((item) {
    myNewList.add("\'$item\'");
  });
}
```

so the print of `myList` would be `[1, 2, 3]`

and the print of `myNewList` would be `['1', '2', '3']`.

by the way...

The order of the quotation signs is arbitrary and the meaning of

`"\'$item\'"`

is the same as

`'\"$item\"'`

The difference is that your output from

`"\'$item\'"`

would be

`['1', '2', '3']`

and the output of

`'\"$item\"'`

would be

`["1", "2", "3"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

`List<String> myList = <String>["'1'","'2'","'3'"];`

Or you can use it this way:

`List<String> myList = <String>['\'1'\','\'2'\','\'3\''];`